# MySQL db call: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I get the error `not all arguments converted during string formatting`, when I execute the below-given code:

```
pro_title = "FSBT"
print "pro_title: " + pro_title
pro_id_query = "SELECT ID FROM projs WHERE pro_title=%s"
cursor.execute(pro_id_query, pro_title)
db.commit()
row = cursor.fetchone()
pro_id = None
if row is not None:
   pro_id = str(row[0])    
print "pro_id: " + pro_id
```

I also tried `format`:

```
pro_id_query = "SELECT ID FROM projs WHERE title={}"
cursor.execute(pro_id_query.format(pro_title))
```

It only works when I use `'` around `{}`:

```
pro_id_query = "SELECT ID FROM projs WHERE title='{}'"
cursor.execute(pro_id_query.format(pro_title))
```

**I do not understand why `INSERT` queries work well with `%s`, while `SELECT` queries do not:**

```
insert_query = "INSERT INTO projs (title, description) VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title`=%s"
cursor.execute(insert_query, (pro_title, pro_description, pro_title))
```

Comment: Try pro_id_query = "SELECT ID FROM projs WHERE pro_title=?"
cursor.execute(pro_id_query, (pro_title,));

Comment: @angel.bonev: I get the error `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pro_title = "FSBI" 
pro_id_query = "SELECT * FROM %s"%(pro_title)
cursor = con.cursor() 
cursor.execute(q) 
result_list = result.fetchall()   
result_list[0][0] 
con.commit() 
con.close()

pro_id_query = cursor.fetchone() while row != False:
print ("The ID is : ", row[0])
```

*edit

```
id = input("Id : ")
name = input("Name : ")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO names (id, name) VALUES("%s", "%s")"""
          %(id, name))
```

Comment: If you assign the last line to a variable it does.

Comment: Which line? This one `pro_id_query = "SELECT * FROM %s"%(pro_title)`?

Comment: If you refer to this line, I get the error `INSERT INTO projs (`title`, `description`) VALUES (TES, TES) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title`=TES (1054, "Unknown column 'TES' in 'field list'")`

Comment: I edited my answer with input aswell. But it does work. I dont know how you have made your table offcourse, then i need to make everything a variable to fix it so that you can put it in manualy. Im sure you can figure it out.