# MySQLdb in python does not rollback the effect of a trigger

Tags: python, triggers, transactions, mysql-python, rollback

In MySQL (version 5.6.32-78.1)
I have 2 *tables* named **Test1**, **Test2** (say),
where **Test1** has a *trigger* (**After INSERT**) inserting something into
a 3rd table called **Test1A**.

I'm using **MySQLdb** module in **python 3.6** to work with my DB.

I'm trying to bundle 2 separate inserts in *Test1* and *Test2* into a single transaction. The problem I have, is that while the entire transaction might be rolled back due to an error in the 2nd insert, the result of the trigger fired after **Insert** in *Test1* is **NOT** being rolled back.

So, after the rollback we get back to the states of tables **Test1** and **Test2** before the transaction, however, the effect of the trigger on **Test1** remains.

Any ideas/suggestions ?

Here is the model code

```
import MySQLdb

cnn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "hostname", user = "username", 
passwd = password", db = "dbname")

cursor = cnn.cursor()

try:

    cursor.execute( "SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0 " )  
    print('done with step 1')

    s  = "Insert INTO Test1 ( field1) Values (%s ) "
    cursor.execute(s, ( 'abc',  ) )  # this fires a trigger 

    print('done with step 2')

    s = "Insert INTO Test2 (ID,  field1) Values (%s, %s)"
    cursor.execute( s , ('1', 'aa'  )  )

    print('done step 3')

    cursor.close()
    cnn.commit()

    print('DONE')

except:
    cnn.rollback()      # the effect of the trigger on Test1 is not being 
    print('Rollbacked') # rolled back
```

The **trigger** on Test1 is

```
INSERT INTO
Test1A (field1)
SELECT
Test1.field1 FROM Test1
WHERE
Test1.ID = NEW.ID
```

A few comments:

If I don't turn off the autocommit, then commit is called on each
insert statement above, so that seems to be necessary.

Of course, one may suggest to put **Test1** as the last table inside
a transaction, but that's not an option, as I might need an info from **Test1** (say new ID) to operate on **Test2**.

Answer (score -1):

Already posted this today but anyway here you go :

```
import pymysql

  id = input("Id : ")
  name = input("Name : ")
  cursor = con.cursor()
  cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO names (id, name) VALUES("%s", "%s")"""
        %(id, name))

        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

You can see my response on this question :
[MySQL db call: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608950/8577333)

Comment: thanks for your reply! But I think the problem I had was different.  The inserts were executing just fine,  but I was having a ``left over'' result from the trigger fired on inserting in one of the tables, which was not being rolled back as part of the transaction.   Anyways, I got some advice that it might be a problem with storage engines in MySql, and indeed it was, the table affected by a trigger was set to MySIAM. I changed that to InnoDB, and the problem is solved.